# How to change values of a running pi script

Tags: python

I have a LED-board which is powered with python.
To turn on the LED's a script has to continue running. But how do I influence the color variables of a running script?

I could read an sql(lite?) db, read the values of a file. Get values of some rest api. Or maybe something completely else.

What is the most neat way to do this?
I'm new to python so feel free to point out I'm completely doing it wrong. 
Or provide alternative.
Please do provide sample code which I could follow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

import unicornhat as unicorn

unicorn.set_layout(unicorn.AUTO)
unicorn.rotation(0)
unicorn.brightness(0.3)

count = 0
while True:

    # somehow change these color values
    # syqlite? reading a file? rest requesting some url? or some signal? how to do this?
    color=[
        [255,0,0], #red
        [255,255,0], #yellow
        [0,255,0], #green
        [0,255,255], #light blue
        [0,0,255], # blue
        [255,0,255], #purple
        [255,255,255], #white
        [0,0,0], #off
    ]


    unicorn.clear()

    for y in xrange(8):

        # make it "scroll"
        row = y+count
        if row>7:
            row -= 8

        for x in xrange(8):
            unicorn.set_pixel(y, x, color[row][0], color[row][1], color[row][2])


    unicorn.show()
    if count == 7:
        count = 0
    else:
        count = count + 1

    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: the easiest way would be to store them in a text file and read it every second so.

Comment: I'll take it into consideration. But it just feels like there should be better/other ways to do it, right? I'm a php guy so this whole 'continues' thing is new to me.